# Generics extends

Tags: java, generics

There's a method:

```
protected List<? extends Object> retrieveData(TypeReference<List<? extends Object>> ref)
```

When I try to apply it:

```
return (List<SomeClass>) retrieveData(new TypeReference<List<SomeClass>>() {});
```

I get this notification

> The method `retrieveData(TypeReference<List<? extends Object>>)` in the
>   type AbstractJsonService is not applicable for the arguments `(new
>   TypeReference<List<SomeClass>>(){})`

Not sure what's wrong here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Not sure what's wrong here. Any suggestions?`

The type `<? extends Object>` is unknown in the method body, this type might be an instance of `List<SomeClass>` or not. The compiler can't know for sure and prevents the returning of a `List<SomeClass>`.

When using a `protected <T> T retrieveData(TypeReference<T> ref)` you have a "fixed" type for T and the compiler knows for sure that the returned type is the same with `TypeReference`'s type. Beside this the compiler is able to infer the type T to be `List<SomeClass>` when calling the method: `retrieveData(new TypeReference<List<SomeClass>>)`, no need anymore to do `List<SomeClass>` cast.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try with the following method signature:

```
protected <E> E retrieveData(TypeReference<E> ref)
```

Comment: It seems to be working - could you explain why it works and why my approach fails to?

Comment: You could use this definition : protected <E extends List<? extends Object>> E retrieveData(TypeReference<E> ref) which will force E to be at least a List